# receive complex object and handle it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, controller

I am working with asp.net web api, and my client side is in vuejs, i pass a object with json that is like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Table",
    "rows": 1,
    "cols": 1,
    "cells": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "Paragraph",
    "text": "asda",
    "fontSize": 14
  },
  {
    "key": "Paragraph",
    "text": "asda",
    "fontSize": 14
  },
  {
    "key": "Paragraph",
    "text": "asda",
    "fontSize": 14
  }
]
```

i need to receive it at a endpoint, at the moment i hit the endpoint but my data is always null.

**Here is my controller:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateDocument([FromBody]DocumentDetails atributes)
{
    return Ok(atributes);
}
```

simple thing, just to see if i receive the data, i created a DocumentDetails object since the data i receive is a List, i have something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace server.Models
{
    public class DocumentDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentAtributes> atributes { set; get; }
    }
}
```

it has a list that is of type DocumentAtributes, where should be all the data that can be in the list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

    namespace server.Models
    {
        public class DocumentAtributes
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public String key { get; set; }
            public String rows { get; set; }
            public String cols { get; set; }
            public String cells { get; set; }
            public String fontSize { get; set; }
            public String width { get; set; }
            public String height { get; set; }
            public String base64 { get; set; }
            public String align { get; set; }
            public String text { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

You are recieving a json array. Your controller should take a List or an array as parameter:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateDocument([FromBody]DocumentAttributes[] atributes)
{
    DocumentDetails details = new DocumentDetails();
    details.atributes = atributes.ToList();
    return Ok(details);
}
```

Comment: ok, now i get the array, but i don't get the values inside, my atributes list is empty, but the DocumentAttributes has data

Comment: Check the edits I have done to the code. I think this is what you are asking for, but not completely sure.

Comment: i can't create a instance of atributes if i don't have them, i mean i recieve the list, but the list is null for the atributes inside the array